# Parallel Requests in ASP.net SQL-Server Session State

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, load-balancing, session-state

I have a question about how ASP.NET handles parallel requests to a SQL Server Session state store in a load balanced scenario. We are using the `Microsoft.AspNet.SessionState.SessionStateModuleAsync` module, web forms and target framework is 4.7.

What happens when two or more requests with the same session id go to the same aspx page. The first request is handled by server1, the second by server2 and the third by server3. At the first request I store a variable in the session and the request is not finished before requests two and three arrived.

Is it possible to read the variable in request two and three before request 1 ends?